# Break large 2D array into multiple smaller 2D array using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array which consist of image pixels which its size depends on the size of the input image. I need to break it into smaller 9x9 arrays. To give a clearer picture, I try to illustrate the situation:

//The number of rows and columns of the smallerArray will look something like this:
It should copy them from the imagePixels array iterating through each 8 columns, then move on to the next 8 rows.

```
    1st small   2nd small            3rd small            and so on..
    array:      array:               array: 
     012345678  91011121314151617   181920212223242526    ....
    0          0                   0
    1          1                   1
    2          2                   2
    3          3                   3
    4          4                   4
    5          5                   5
    6          6                   6
    7          7                   7
    8          8                   8

    Then move on to next 8 rows:

      012345678    91011121314151617   181920212223242526    ....
    9             9                   9
    10           10                  10
    11           11                  11
    12           12                  12
    13           13                  13
    14           14                  14
    15           15                  15
    16           16                  16
    17           17                  17

.
.
.
```

I have done the following code but could not get my logic right. How can I stop the iteration:

> Copy up until the 9th column or row, store it in an array, resume copying on the 10th column/row, stop when it reaches 9 column/row after, store it in another array, and keep on doing that till it finishes copying the imagePixels array.

I tried to store the arrays in an ArrayList so it would be easier for me to manipulate and do calculation stuffs with all the smallerArrays.

```
ArrayList<double[][]> collectionofSmallArrays = new ArrayList();
double[][] imagePixels = new double[1600][1000]; //Lets say this is the size of the image
double[][] smallerArray = new double[9][9];

for(int a = 0; a<smallerArray.length; a++)
{
  for(int b =0; b<smallerArray[a].length; b++)
  { 
    for(int c=0; c<imagePixels.length; c++)
    {
      for(int d=0; d<imagePixels[c].length; d++)
      {
        smallerArray[a][b] = imagePixels[c][d];
        ...(code to stop the iteration if it reaches 9, store it in array then resume where it stops     with another new array)
        collectionofSmallArrays.add(smallerArray);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone work around the code to achieve the expected result? Appreciate it.

Comment: First of all you need to decide what output you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably provide more context information. Saying that an array of `double` values represents *pixels* sounds dubios. If you are working with images, then you might find solutions on a *completely* different level of abstraction (I'm thinking about [BufferedImage#createSubImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) here).

However, to answer the question: You should break the task up into smaller parts. Particularly, it might be easier to implement two methods:

- One method that receives an input array, some coordinates, and an output array, and that copies the data from the specified coordinates of the input array to the output array
- One method that calls the above mentioned method with the appropriate coordinates to split the whole array into the parts of the desired size.

In pseudocode:

```
for (each coordinates (9*r,9*c)) {
    copy the rectange (9*r,9*c)-(9*r+9,9*c+9) of the input array into an array
```

A very simple implementation/test is shown in the following example. Note that this could be generalized and improved, but I think it shows the basic idea:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubArrayTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double inputArray[][] = createInputArray(160, 100);
        System.out.println("inputArray: "+toString(inputArray));

        List<double[][]> subArrays = createSubArrays(inputArray, 9, 9);

        for (double subArray[][] : subArrays)
        {
            System.out.println("subArray:\n"+toString(subArray));
        }
    }

    private static List<double[][]> createSubArrays(
        double inputArray[][], int subRows, int subCols)
    {
        List<double[][]> subArrays = new ArrayList<double[][]>();
        for (int r=0; r<inputArray.length; r+=subRows)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<inputArray[r].length; c+=subCols)
            {
                double subArray[][] = new double[subRows][subCols]; 
                fillSubArray(inputArray, r, c, subArray);
                subArrays.add(subArray);
            }
        }
        return subArrays;
    }

    private static void fillSubArray(
        double[][] inputArray, int r0, int c0, double subArray[][])
    {
        for (int r=0; r<subArray.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<subArray[r].length; c++)
            {
                int ir = r0 + r;
                int ic = c0 + c;
                if (ir < inputArray.length &&
                    ic < inputArray[ir].length)
                {
                    subArray[r][c] = inputArray[ir][ic];
                }
            }
        }
    }


    //===Test methods=========================================================
    private static double[][] createInputArray(int rows, int cols)
    {
        double array[][] = new double[rows][cols]; 
        for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++)
            {
                array[r][c] = r*100+c;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static String toString(double array[][])
    {
        String format = "%7.1f";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int r=0; r<array.length; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<array[r].length; c++)
            {
                sb.append(String.format(format, array[r][c])+" ");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

---

Side notes:

- You should always declare variables with their interface type. This means that you should not write

  ```
  ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```

  but always

  ```
  List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
  ```
- In the posted code, you seemed to always add the **same instance** of the sub-array to the list. This means that in the end you would have many instances of the same array in the list, all with the same content. Somewhere in between you have to create a `new double[9][9]` array.

Answer (score 0):

`smallerArray[a][b] = imagePixels[c][d]` line looks strange. You reuse same array instance. Your output array list will contain multiple reference to same array.

Comment: I know. That's the problem I am asking. How can I stop the iteration and resume on new array.

Comment: create new array in loop.

Comment: And also your loops are strange. Can you try to explain how you  think it work?

Comment: Yes it looked strange because I couldn't get my logic right. I include the question in the code just for all of you to actually get a rough idea what I'm doing. Basically I'm trying to slice the imagePixels array into smaller arrays using 9x9 block.

Comment: Yes. I get it. But in my opinion you don't understand how loops work. I try to understand the poit from which I'll try to start my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot reuse `smallerArray`. Create the instance inside the for loop and store the size in a constant.
2. I think a map with some corner coordinates as a key would be far better than a list for storing your results.
3. What happens if the length or width or your image is not divisible by 9?

Comment: There's a block of code to deal with images not divisible by 9 earlier in the code which I did not include in this question. Just having a hard time to break the big array i into smaller arrays.